# Unload the content in a div for next set of results

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I search for first time, I get perfect results, but when I search any thing for the second time, it appends the second set of the results with the first set of results, if I use .html, then of course it prints the last value. How can I unload the first set of results and print the next set of results. Is there an AJAX method for this or I have to use any jquery event?

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search_btn').click(function(){

var search_string = $('#search_string').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'my-site/restapi/vc/search/messages?q='+search_string,
    success: function(data){

     $(data).find("message > subject").each(function () {

    $('#results').append( $(this).text()+'<br>');
    });
    }

});
});
});
</script>
<div id="search-area">
<p><input id="search_string" type="text"/></p>
<p><input id="search_btn" type="button" value="Search"/></p>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: But i have a list of results, an XML, so if I use .html, it always prints the last element in the XML DOM, so I have to use .append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try remove the first result after ajax success using

**$('#results').html("");**

```
$.ajax({
url: 'my-site/restapi/vc/search/messages?q='+search_string,
success: function(data){
 $('#results').html("");
 $(data).find("message > subject").each(function () {

$('#results').append( $(this).text()+'<br>');
});
}
});
```